# Why is the behavior of Python generators different when they're being updated in a for loop?

Tags: python

I was playing around with the following code in Python 3.8:

```py
a = range(10)
limits = (5, 3) # order of limits doesn't matter
a = (i for i in a if i > limit[0])
a = (i for i in a if i > limit[1])
print(list(a))
```

As referenced in the comment, it doesn't matter which limit is being applied first in this case; whether `limits = (5, 3)` or `(3, 5)`, the output on the last line is `[6, 7, 8, 9]` in both cases. However, this is no longer the case with a (seemingly) inconsequential refactor of the code:

```py
a = range(10)
limits = (5, 3) # order of limits matters now?
for limit in limits:
    a = (i for i in a if i > limit)
print(list(a))
```

With the refactor, if `limits = (3, 5)`, then the resulting output is `[6, 7, 8, 9]`, but with `limits = (5, 3)`, the output equals `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. It seems like only the final filter is applied in this case; when I ran the following code:

```py
a = range(10)
limits = (4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
for limit in limits:
    a = (i for i in a if i > limit)
print(list(a))
```

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` was the output. Can someone explain why this behavior is happening?

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the refactored version, the value of the `limit` variable is looked up when the generators *generate* values, not when the generator objects are created.

Since value *generation* only happens on the last line with `list(a)`, at this time the value of `limit` is whatever it was for the last iteration of the loop.